# Regarding prevState callback in .setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Case1.

```js
    handleRemovePlayer = id => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                players: prevState.players.filter(player => player.id !== id)
            };
        });
    };
```

Case2.

```js
    // Arrow Func: become Component instance
    incrementScore = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            score: this.state.score + 1
        }));
    };
    decrementScore = () => {
        if (this.state.score > 0) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                score: this.state.score - 1
            }));
        }
    };
```

In setState(), why case1 cannot use `this.players.filter` instead of `prevState.player`? Both case1 and 2 use the same `prevState` callback.. Can anyone explain precisely regarding prevState?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ^^ `incrementScore` and `decrementScore` should be using `prevState.score + 1`, not `this.state.score + 1`.

Comment: It would use `this.state.players.filter`, not `this.players.filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `setState()` is asynchronous inside event handlers.

Let assume that- you updated your state and you want to check state is updated or not.

for that you can use updater(callback) as 2nd argument to check updated state.

like this -

```
    incrementScore = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          score: prevState.score + 1
      }),()=>{
        console.log(this.state.score)
      });
  };
```

Calls to `setState` are asynchronous - don’t rely on `this.state` to reflect the new value immediately after calling `setState`. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state ...for your reference [setState in reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

SetState is an asynchronous method. So, if there are more than 1 setState execution methods, the second approach may result in the value which we are not interested in. But the first approach will make sure we always get the latest state value.

One should always use `prevState` instead of `this.state`.